# How to display details during Linux system shutdown?

Tags: linux, shutdown, arch-linux

By using "details" here, I am talking something like this:

```
[  OK  ] Stopped Getty on tty1.
[  OK  ] Stopped Entropy Harvesting Daemon.
[  OK  ] Unmounted Temporary /etc/pacman.d/gnupg directory.
..
```

So when something fails here, I can figure it out easily.

Answer (score -3):

When you are on the splash screen, just press the <kbd>Escape</kbd> button .